# LinkedIn Authdata JSON Parsing Issue

Tags: json, customer-portal, auth, linkedin

We have enabled LinkedIn registration and Signin for our community users. While providing the User Info Endpoint URL for creating the Auth Provider in Salesforce, we specified the following to get details such as Company Name, Photo URL, etc which are by default not provided.

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,email-address,industry,picture-url,headline,positions)

The response we get is kind of JSON but cannot be deserialized. Below is an example:

> {_total=1, values=[{isCurrent=true, company={size=2-10, name=Test
>   Company Name, industry=Information Technology & Services, id=3556012,
>   type=Privately Held}, location={name=Texas}, id=867629074,
>   title=Tester, startDate={month=8, year=2016}}]}

As you can see, this text has = instead of : and doesn't has double quotes for labels and values.

Questions:

- Is there an easy way to add double quotes? The replace of = is not an issue.
- Is there a way to specify that the response should be JSON or even XML? The linkedIn guide mentions adding ?format=json to the url but Salesforce doesn't allows us doing that.

EDIT:
We tried adding ?format=json in the endpoint but Salesforce throws an error. See the attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: Why can not you add format=json ?

Comment: Salesforce throws an error saying "format not allowed in the endpoint"

Comment: so, is that thrown by Salesforce or returned by LinkedIn? I am afraid it is not possible to add quotes without knowing proper response

Comment: @kurunve Have added screenshot of error we get. The error is at salesforce end while defining the auth provider.